# Accidentally restored from husband's iPhone backup, how to undo?

Tags: ios, backup

I accidentally deleted an important message on my iPhone. I thought with iTunes and iCloud I could undelete it. Unfortunately, I did not read a dialog box and now my husband's iPhone backup has been restored to *my* iPhone.

My iPhone and his iPhone are now the same, and I get his phone calls, messages, and more.

How can I change my iPhone back to my old iPhone? This is urgent. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

1. Settings app > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings
2. Load your [last backup from iCloud or iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766)

**Caution:** If you have someone else assist that has familiarity with what exact message is presented during sync and restore, you'll be less likely to make a second mistake since getting things done AWAP (As Well As Possible) is better in the long run than ASAP (As Soon As Possible).

Check what happened, you might have told an iTunes library with your husband's information to sync just contacts and calendars and preserving the majority of your phone's apps, settings and content. If that's the case, you might be able to undo things if you have an iTunes library with your data and repeat the "wipe" but with your preferred set of contacts and calendar data. Also, restoring an iOS device will restore past call history, but  the phone number on your phone is still yours so even if your phone has someone else's data on it, it's still your phone and not theirs for all new calls/messages that come and go.